# How can I update a specific docker image when changes are applied

Tags: docker

**Question 1:**
Do I have to update both the container and the image, or just the image?

**Question 2:**
When I make changes to the data in which the my app uses, how can I update the docker image or container(if necessary), so that the app will show and update data from updated image/container.
I have the current docker image running named: `test/app1`

- List item

**Here are my current steps:**

_1. Rebuild the application using: `docker build -t test/app1`

_2.Restart Docker using: `service docker restart`

**After these steps are made there are no errors but the image does not have the updated data. Is this an issue with the Image update or Container.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you do'nt have to restart `docker` service!

To answer your first question:

> Question 1: Do I have to update both the container and the image, or
>   just the image?

Just update the image, stop old container, `docker run` new container from new image.

> Question 2: When I make changes to the data in which the my app uses,
>   how can I update the docker image or container(if necessary), so that
>   the app will show and update data from updated image/container. I have
>   the current docker image running named: test/app1

Depends on your app data, If its mounted via bind mount, or volume, your just have to update these, If your app requires restart some service to make that data available, you can stop/start the container or remove/recreate it.

If your data is in the image/container, You update the image, stop the old container and recreate it using the new image.

Comment: So once I update the image, I would just build the image as `docker build -t test/app1`, stop the container(how should I do this), then run the command `docker run test/app1`?

Comment: when you build an image, you create a new image, try adding tags to the new image, such as version number. `docker build -t test/app1:1.1`. to stop the container, Use 'docker stop <containername or ID>` to stop the container, and `docker rm <container name or id>` to remove it. then run a new container from new image. `docker run test/app1:1.1`

Comment: I worry about this method as I am using a ShinyProxy server which references the image name : `test/app1` in its configuration settings. So i use `docker run test/app1`. Is that ok?

Comment: if you replace the old image with the new, you should be fine